# missing term life insurance policy papers

Tags: united-states, life-insurance, documents, term-life

We are missing term life insurance policies, but making yearly payments. In case a something wrong happens? Will the policy number alone will be sufficient to make a claim ?

I also see there are companies who are [holding](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/personalfinance/2016/06/11/unclaimed-life-insurance-money-payout/85718732/) payments.

Answer (score 10):

The insurance company should have a webpage that will allow you to see lots of documents related to your policies. If the documents you want are not there, you should be able to either contact your agent, or use the contact information on the website to request copies of the documents. In my case I would ask my agent, but not everybody has a local agent.

The policy numbers, relevant dates, and the amounts of insurance should be kept in a document called a death book so that a trusted person has access to all that information. This book should also have documents related to bank accounts, retirement accounts, and your will. One thing you will want to include is the page that lists who gets the money from the policy.

The yearly bill should also have enough information (the policy number) so that somebody can start a claim, even if the rest of related information is unknown.

Comment: Right, there shouldn't be any hesitation to contact the insurance company. Call and ask them to send or email you a copy of your policy.